# Не могу доработать скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть меню, которое изначально скрыто и открывается только при клике, причем при разворачивании подпунктов меню должен появляться эффект набора текста.Я написал скрипт но работает он коряво: При нажатии на кнопку текст появляется, эффект срабатывает, при повторном клике меню скрывается, но обратно потом не разворачивается, как исправить эту проблему?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var menuBtn = $('.menu_btn');
  var menu = $('.effects');

  menuBtn.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    menu.removeClass();
    menu.toggleClass('effects-active');

  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu_btn').click(function() {
    $('.effects-active').typeIt({
      speed: 35,
      autoStart: true,
    });
    if ($('#eff').hasClass('.effects')) {
      $('.effects-active').typeIt({
          speed: 35,
          autoStart: true,
        })
        .reset();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.effects {
  display: none;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.effects-active {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.menu_items {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
 
<link href='../fonts/SeoulHangangCondensed-Light.ttf' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.typeit/4.4.0/typeit.min.js"></script>
<section class="main">
  <div class="container-fluid main top-nav_content">
    <div class="row justify-content-start align-items-center">
      <div class="menu">
        <ul class="top-nav_menu">
          <button class="menu_btn"></button>
          <div class="effects" id="eff">
            <li class="menu_items"><a class="menu_items__link" href="#" link="#211E56">Первый пункт</a></li>
            <li class="menu_items"><a class="menu_items__link" href="#" link="#211E56">Второй пункт</a></li>
            <li class="menu_items"><a class="menu_items__link" href="#" link="#211E56">Третий пункт</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Могу ошибаться. Но по-моему ошибка в строке menu.removeClass(); Получается вы сначала удаляете все классы с элемента, а потом делаете toggleClass т.е. всегда включаете этот класс.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: И класс effect при этом пропадает

Comment: Убрал эту строчку. Теперь при повторном клике курсор пропадает вместе с пунктами меню, но как и прежде при последующем нажатии появляется один только курсор, без текста.

Comment: Я в принципе понимаю в чем проблема, но не знаю как её решить: плагин, который отвечает за эффект набора текста, при закрытии меню продолжает работать, а он должен отключаться при повторном нажатии на кнопку и при последующем нажатии запускаться заново

Comment: и много текста планируется выводит? этот плагин, на каждую букву создаёт новую текстовую ноду, таким образом, если у вас текст в 10000 символов, то он создать 10000 нод, что может сказаться негативно на производительности

Comment: Нет, буквально 4-5 слов, не более.